# How to make a collage thumbnail

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How Can I make a collage thumbnail like they have in flicker ?? where can I learn to make a kind of gallery like [this one](https://www.flickr.com/explore)

Comment: Download the page and try to understand, how you want to use. if you face any problem then ask.

Comment: which page should i download?

Comment: the page in your link https://www.flickr.com/explore go here and save this page as complete html and change its url and learn its coding flow.

Comment: Ctrl + S to save the document, remember to save all files.

Comment: Here you can learn: http://w3bits.com/css-masonry/ Just, adapt it to your convenience :)